# Add rgb node not working correctly in cycles

Tags: shaders

I made a simple scroll made from 2 textures, first is the written text with transparent background, second one is the base parchment color. I use add RGB node to join the 2 textures. In eve (picture 1) and material view (picture 2) it works well but in cycles (picture 3) the text is basically transparent. Why doesn't it work is there another way to achieve wanted result?

[image: eve] [image: material view] [image: cycles]]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show all the nodes?

Comment: I have a pretty small screen so the image isn't the best quality

Comment: can you show textures also?

Comment: I am not sure if i am legally allowed to redistribute the textures. I will remake the materials by myself  in a way that gets the same results and then post .blend file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see now. It's because how EEVEE and CYCLES works.

You have black-and-white text. In Cycles, it doesn't matter how dark it is you may multiply it by 1000, it will be black and white. Nothing really changes.

[image]

But when it goes to EEVEE, there is a difference. EEVEE generates mipmaps then the texture is too small in screenspace. So instead black-and-white sharp text you will get blurred (because of low resolution) gray text that you can really make darker.

[image]

[image]

So to get the same result in cycles, make your font bolder, or generate a small version of your texture, like a mipmap do

Answer (score 0):

If you use the *Image Texture*'s *Color* output it will interpret the alpha channel as black so you'll get a completely black mask, so instead use the *Alpha* output. Also invert the colors and use *Multiply* or *Mix* instead of *Add*:

[image]

Comment: It works a bit better but the colors still get "blown out" in cycles.

Comment: could you please pack your images and share your object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I am new to blender so it will take me some time to figure out how to do that :)

Comment: keep only the parchment object, go into File > External Data > Pack Resources, then save, and use a platform like pasteall.org/blend  (upload, it will generate a URL, copy paste it here)

Comment: It should be available for download..

Comment: yes, I've downloaded it but for me it works fine in both Eevee and Cycles

Comment: interesting, i am using blender 3.1 so it might be buggy, or is it possible to be hardware connected?

Comment: I'm also using 3.1, see what it gives: https://zupimages.net/up/22/13/axxf.png ... maybe disconnect the Displacement to see what it gives?

Comment: I am using 3.1 as well, it looks normal for me. What is very distracting is the bump and displacement and the line structure on the paper color itself. Also, this is a very fine scripture and what Eevee and the Material Preview don't do very well is antialiasing the fine lines so that the impression of thin lines is preserved. Zooming out the lines appear thicker in Eevee and Material Preview. That's why you think in Cycles they are washed out. If you zoom in very close, the thickness seems the same in Eevee and Cycles, but zooming out they get thicker in Eevee.

Comment: @ Gordon Brinkmann it looks like it is what Crantisz explains?

Comment: @moonboots Yes, when I started writing my comment the answer wasn't visible ;) And he explained it better and more detailed. By the way, if you leave spaces between the @ and the names, I won't get notified that you mentioned me :D

Comment: oh ok I didn't know that, thanks  ;)